# IPC between a windows service and a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, service, windows-services, ipc

What is the best/easiest way to setup interprocess communication between
a windows service and a webservice? The windows service will be running on
the same machine that is hosting the web service.

The web service will be calling the windows service to some information ?

I know its possible using namedpipes, Sharedmemory, WCF etc. But I'm looking for something that doesn't add complexity in terms security.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't add complexity in terms security"? Communication between 2 processes running under different accounts will always have security implications...

Comment: [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xws7132e.aspx) used to be an easy way to do IPC, but Microsoft is phasing this out in favor of WCF.  If you want to do it right (the way that will be around and supported for some time going forward), WCF is the way to go.